# sqoop export commands for the data which has spaces before in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

i have data which has stored in hdfs, the data has space before and after of the value, when i try to export to mysql, it gives numberformat exception but when i create data without space, it has inserted into mysql successfully.

```
my question is can't we export the data which has space from hdfs to mysql usong sqoop export command?

The data which i used
1201, adi, sen manager,   30000,  it
1201, pavan, jun manager, 5000,    cs
1203, santhosh, junior,    60000,  mech

i created table like
create table emp(id BIGINT,name varchar(20),desg varchar(20),salary BIGINT,dept varchar(20));

sqoop command -- sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb \
--username root \
--table emp \
--m 1 \
--export-dir /mydir \
--input-fields-terminated-by ',' \
--input-lines-terminated-by '\n'

result: numberformatexception input string:'1201'
can't parse the data

i discussed in forum, they said trim the space but i wants to know that automatically trim the spaces while perform sqoop export.

can somebody give suggestions on this?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do 1 simple thing:

Create temporary table in MySQL with all `VARCHAR`

```
create table emp-temp(id BIGINT,name varchar(20),desg varchar(20),salary BIGINT,dept varchar(20));
```

Now create another with numeric fields after [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) and [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

```
create table emp as select CAST(TRIM(id) AS UNSIGNED), name, desg, CAST(TRIM(salary) AS UNSIGNED), dept FROM emp_temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sqoop** internally runs MapReduce job.

Simple solution is to run a **Mapper** and **trim** the spaces in your data and get the output in different file and run **sqoop export** on new file.

Comment: I tried the data from sqoop tutorials point https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqoop/

Comment: can somebody try the same data and let me know, i definitely sure you would also get the number format exception